# Populating ListView with ArrayList<Object>

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to populate a ListView with an ArrayList.
The ArrayList contains Usuarios Objects. Usuario has two fields (String nombre, String edad).
This is my code:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios = (ArrayList<Usuario>) dao.showAll();

ArrayAdapter<Usuario> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Usuario>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaUsuarios);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I test my Android App, it looks like this:

[image]

The ListView doesn't show the Usuario fields (nombre, edad) it shows es.dga.sqlitetest.Usuario@43e4...

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide a `toString()` method for `Usuario`. Something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
 return this.label;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly but I don't understand why it works, can you explain?

Comment: method #getView() from adapter will return the view inflated from android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. That is a simple textview. Its setText() will be called with getItem(int position).toString() which will return a Usuario.toString(); If you need more complex view or customization you can override getView().

Answer (score 2):

What you see in your screenshot are the memory addresses of the objects from your list. The default behavior of the ArrayAdapter is to call the `toString()`method on each object in the array. If you don't override that `toString()` method you get the default with this result.

#### Quick Solution

Override the `toString()`method in your `Usuario` object:

```
class Usuario {
    // whatever you already had in place

    // the name to display in the list
    private String name = "some default value";

    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

#### Better Solution

Create your custom adapter that has a collection of `Usuario`objects so you can inflate your view and display exactly the details that are needed. Some good information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling the *built-in* `toString()` function on your `Usuario` objects.

You need to override it to implement your own in which you can retrieve the individual fields form the the objects (maybe by using something like `mObject.getNombre()` and `mObject.getEdad()` or just `this.label`).

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
Also look up ArrayAdapter interface:

```
  ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```